# Como trazer mais campos no groupby do Pandas, sem necessariamente precisar usá-los no agrupamento?

Tags: python, group-by

Boa tarde, pessoal. Estou mexendo com a biblioteca Pandas no Python e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida, se possível. Eu tenho uma lista de valores e preciso reduzir esta lista para apenas um registro por data. O critério é que o terceiro campo (contador) seja o maior de sua respectiva data. Para fazer isso, usei o seguinte código:

```
import pandas as pd

lista = [("2020-11-16", "803", 4),
    ("2020-11-16", "801", 18),
    ("2020-11-16", "802", 20),
    ("2020-11-17", "801", 12),
    ("2020-11-17", "802", 6)]

df = pd.DataFrame(lista)
df.columns=['data', 'codigo', 'contador']
df2 = df.groupby('data')['contador'].max()
for i in df2.items():
    data = i[0]
    contador = i[1]
    print(data, contador)

#O resultado obtido foi o seguinte e está correto: 
['2020-11-16', 20]
['2020-11-17', 12]
```

A minha dúvida seria se é possível trazer junto neste resultado a coluna 'codigo', sem que esta passe por agrupamento. Se eu a colocar no groupby terei vários registros por data e estará errado, pois só posso ter um único registro por data. Teria alguma maneira de fazer isso, seja pelo pandas ou de outra maneira? Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução seria criar um 'filtro':

```
filtro = df.groupby('data')['contador'].max()
```

E depois utilizar o isin do pandas:

```
df[df['contador'].isin(filtro)].reset_index(drop = True)
```

Saída:

```
    data        codigo  contador
0   2020-11-16    802        20
1   2020-11-17    801        12
```

Comment: @imonferrari, bela solução! Não tenho o hábito de usar o método `isin()`, pois normalmente trabalho com a base toda. Com certeza me fará pensar diferente de agora em diante.

Comment: Opa! Agradeço, Paulo! `isin` é um método bem rápido, depois que começa a usar se torna um vício kkkk. Brincadeiras a parte... Grande Abraço!

Comment: Perfeito. Não conhecia essa possibilidade de filtro com o isin(). Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o que você esteja procurando é o `aggregate`

Para obter o resultado, basta:

1. Criar uma estrutura de funções desejadas para cada campo

```
f = {'contador': 'max', 'codigo': 'first'}
```

2. Faça o `groupby` com `agg` passando `f` como parâmetro

```
df2 = series = df.groupby('data', as_index=False)[['contador', 'codigo']].agg(f)
```

O resultado será:

```
>>> df2
         data  contador codigo
0  2020-11-16        20    803
1  2020-11-17        12    801
```

Perceba que o código escolhido pelo aggregate foi o `first`, o que no caso é o `803`. Porém, caso você queira o mesmo que está na linha do `contador=20`, ou seja, `codigo=802` faça exatamente o que vc estava fazendo e depois conclua com um `merge()`

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df, on=['data', 'contador'])
```

O resultado será:

```
>>> df3
         data  contador codigo
0  2020-11-16        20    802
1  2020-11-17        12    801
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Fala Paulo, boa noite! Tudo bom?  Em um data frame maior parece que cria colunas codigo_x e codigo_y. Creio que tenha que excluir a codigo_x pro resultado ficar igual ao que ele pede no problema. Grande Abraço!

Comment: @imonferrari, obrigado pelo comentário. Os campos que existem nos dois dataframes recebem automaticamente os sufixos`_x` e `_y`. Particularmente eu prefiro passar os sufixos como parâmetro no merge. Algo como `suffixes=('_df1', '_df2')` ou `suffixes=('_left', '_right')`. Outros parâmetros bem úteis são `left_on` e `right_on` que permitem juntar dataframes quando os campos possuem nomes diferentes. Veja mais detalhes do merge [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Comment: Sim, foi só uma observação mesmo para a resposta "sair" do jeito que ele espera, no mais ta tudo nos conformes kkkk. Abraço!!

Comment: Testei aqui também com o aggregate e deu certo também, obrigado Paulo. É bom saber que temos caminhos diferentes para fazer isso. Agradeço muito pelas duas respostas, até mais pessoal.